# Remember_token not stored into db

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to store the remember_token into the database but it is not storing into db. I'm new in `laravel 4` so I don't have any idea how to use it.

```
if (Auth::attempt($userdata,true)) {
 return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
```

I also pass the second parameter as `true` to store the remember_token into database.
But when I logged in into account the `remember_token` remain empty. Plz help me.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is it a new installation of laravel, if not you'll have to add the methods for it in the User.php.

You can read about this in the documentation for that upgrade here: http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade